# Bean properties are not being set through setters

Tags: java, spring

I have the following bean configuration :

```xml
<bean class="com.MyFactoryBean" depends-on="otherBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="defaultDataSource"/>
    <property name="myCustomProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="test">HELLO</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then my class

```
public class MyFactoryBean {
     public MyFactoryBean(final DataSource dataSource) {
          // myConstructor
     }
    public void setMyCustomProperties(final Properties myCustomProperties) {
          System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

While the dataSource is being passed to the constructor, the customProperties are not.

Comment: Do you have an error at run-time? If so what is it?

Comment: I cannot find any errors being logged. However I am definite that the setter was not called

Comment: The way I see it, this can't work because there is no default constructor for `MyFactoryBean`

Comment: The constructor with the parameter is called however

Comment: _Are you sure_? How did you assert that the constructor is called and that the setter isn't called?

Comment: Where do you call the bean? Because scope="prototype" beans are created (and setters called) when this bean is get for the first time.

Comment: @mangusbrother did you solve this issue? if yes, how did you do?

Comment: The issue was that this bean was not actually being loaded but it was being constructed manually from another location.

Comment: @mangusbrother Please, add your answer and solve this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that this bean was not actually being loaded but it was being constructed manually from another location

Answer (score 4):

1. Scope prototype means that every time you ask spring using getBean or dependency injection, for an instance it will create a new instance.
2. Missing default constructor.

**Class**

```
public class MyFactoryBean {
        private DataSource dataSource;
        private Properties myCustomProperties;

        public void setDataSource(final DataSource dataSource) {
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
        }
        public void setMyCustomProperties(final Properties myCustomProperties) {
            this.myCustomProperties = myCustomProperties;
        }
    }
```

**XML config**

```
<bean class="com.MyFactoryBean" depends-on="otherBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="defaultDataSource"/>
    <property name="myCustomProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="test">HELLO</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Furthermore if you want use an hybrid solution you can use your Class and below configuration.

```
<bean class="com.MyFactoryBean" depends-on="otherBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="defaultDataSource" />
    <property name="myCustomProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="test">HELLO</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```